# nginx passenger rails No data received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am new to nginx and passenger and want to use it to run a rails application.

I have installed nginx and passenger on my mac (`passenger-install-nginx-module`).

I can start the nginx server and see the default nginx welcome screen.

I want to run a rails app on my nginx server.

I have added the following to the **nginx.conf**:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name localhost;
  root /myrailsApp/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

When I start my nginx server and navigate to localhost:8080 I see the message:

> "No data received" (Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

I am guessing this is a silly mistake that I have overlooked? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

---

Bit more information that may help.

which ruby returns:

> /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby

I installed using:

> gem install passenger

passenger-config --root returns:

> /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/passenger-4.0.20

Is this (`@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/passenger-4.0.20`) not a little strange ?

I then ran the passenger nginx installer:

> passenger-install-nginx-module

As I said, I can start nginx with no problems. I added the new server block to the nginx.conf file pointing to my rails public folder but the page returns

> "No data received"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks bit unexpected Error, Below configuration working for me. Once try it out.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1;
    passenger_max_pool_size 10;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;
      access_log /var/www/access.log;
      error_log  /var/www/error.log;

     location / {
        root   /var/www/demo/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
     }

     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still no joy :(

Comment: Could you please tell me what Error you getting now?

Comment: [ 2013-10-11 14:38:00.7839 99468/0x7fff74223180 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:669 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
2013/10/11 14:38:19 [alert] 99474#0: worker process 99475 exited on signal 6
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
2013/10/11 14:38:20 [alert] 99474#0: worker process 99495 exited on signal 6

Comment: @JonWilliams If this answer didn't work for you, why did you accept the answer?